# Problem with sizing form contents relative to the menu

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

Basically, i have the menu strip sitting on the chessboard i drew. I don't want this so i try to stretch the board so the board will go down (it has labels that aren't attached to the board/`tablelayoutpanel` itself). How can i make the `menustrip` above not sit on any object on the form?

P.S. i remember i did it by going to the forms properties, but i forgot how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your non-menu, or chessboard part of the UI, should be in some sort of container such as a `Panel`. (This will be a top-level container that will contain your `Label`s as well as your `TableLayoutPanel`.) Set that container's Dock property to Fill in the properties (that's probably the step you're forgetting.)

Also: Docking is highly dependent on the order of object declaration/initialization which is controlled easily by the Move To Front/Send To Back commands in the designer's context menu. To make sure you have the correct order, click on your container object in the designer and select ***Bring To Front*** from the context menu to make sure the fill docking happens after the Top docking of the menu.

Comment: lol..all you need is to select all of the items and drag them...hahah.. now i remembered. thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 0):

Just set your form's attribute `MainMenuStrip` to your `MenuStrip` control and it should appear "docked". If that isn't the issue, a screenshot might be useful as I'm not 100% sure on what your issue is.